# Asp:table bordercolor different html rendered for 1.1 and 2.0

Tags: asp.net

I have the following markup .NET 1.1 app.

I want the grid lines of the table to be darkgray this is the goal here.

```
<asp:table id="tbl" Runat="server" CellSpacing="0" BorderColor="darkgray" GridLines="Both"></asp:table>
```

I have the app in IIS set as ver 1.1 in my dev box
and 2.0 in production for various reasons.

The page source in 1.1 renders this

```
<table id="ctlTimesheetMonthly_tbl" cellspacing="0" rules="all" bordercolor="DarkGray" border="1" style="border-color:DarkGray;border-collapse:collapse;">`
```

2.0 renders this

```
<table id="ctlTimesheetMonthly_tbl" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-color:DarkGray;border-collapse:collapse;">
```

Which is wrong as it produces a white border for some reason.

Any idea how to get both the same??

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?

The differences are almost certainly caused by a combination of out of date browser capabilities settings in your 1.1 server and CSS rules, but annoyingly, that appears to be giving you the behaviour you want (in my experience, it's usually the other way around :(

An updated set of Browser Caps settings for both versions can be found here:

> [Browser Detective and BrowserCaps Resources](http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/)

On the CSS side, I'd look at setting the border colour etc in a css class, referenced through the CssClass property of the table, and make sure (using FireBug or IE Developer Tools) that there are no other styles affecting your table.